# Simplify raster size to plot using ggplot geom_raster()

Tags: raster, r, mapping, ggplot2

I want to create a map using 'ggplot2'. My data contains shapefile (points data), polygons (European countries). Underneath the vector data, I wanted to place the raster showing extends of forests over Europe, available [here](https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/european-forest-areas-based-on). The raster size of disk is 150 MB, has dimension of 46000 and 65000. To use it in ggplot, I need to first convert it to dataframe: `raster_df<-as.data.frame(raster)`.

But, I got an error: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 11.1 G`. I do not understand why I got this error? How to make sure that I can plot my raster with vector data using `ggplot2`?

Dummy example:

```
# read raster
forest <- raster(paste(getwd(), "eea_r_3035_100_m_forest-area-2015_p_2015_v1_r1.tif", sep = "/"))

# convert to dataframe for ggplot2()
forest_df <- as.data.frame(forest, xy = TRUE) 

# Plot the raster data on top of European countries
ggplot(data = europe) + 
geom_fs() +
geom_raster(data = forest)
```

---

EDIT:

I have increased my `memory.limit(12000)` and this allows me to create a `dataframe` or a `stars` object that I can both plot with `ggplot2`. But, the display still takes forewer. When I visualize the map in ArcGIS or QGIS, the plotting takes a second. Isn't there something as efficient to plot rasters and use them in a map in R? `tmap::tm_raster()` seems promissing but other suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems an error in allocating enough memory size. Check memory allocation by `memory.limit()`:

```
memory.limit()
[1] 4002
```

Then you can increase - let's say triple - the allocated memory size.

```
memory.limit(12000)
[1] 12000
```

---

I used `stars` package as below, but your code should work after increasing the memory allocation;

```
library(ggplot2)
library(stars)

f = "C:/Users/userr/Downloads/ForestArea2015/eea_r_3035_100_m_forest-area-2015_p_2015_v1_r1.tif"
forest = read_stars(f, NA_value = 65535)

ggplot() +
  geom_stars(data = forest, downsample = 10) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low= "white", high = "green")+
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks you for nice display and way how to use `stars` object within ggplot! I have discovered `stars` just recently, and I am still quite confuse about them...

Comment: @Kazuito, still it takes forewer to run and plot it. Is there any other way how to effectively plot the raster data? One way is to simply crop it. It takes a second to plot it in ArcGIS or in QGIS. How to do it in R but with the same ease?

Comment: @maycca Same here, when I use ggplot2. But `plot(forest)` will show the map instantly.